# tesseract install mac os

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, tesseract

I am trying to install tesseract on my mac using homeBrew. When I try installing, everything seems to be good but I get the following error/message:

```
Warning: Could not link leptonica. Unlinking...
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link leptonica'
```

When I try running a tesseract function, I get the following error:

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02.02 with Leptonica
Error in pixReadStreamPng: function not present
Error in pixReadStream: png: no pix returned
Error in pixRead: pix not read
Unsupported image type.
```

I have image magick installed and the command I used to install tesseract was:

```
brew install tesseract
```

Can anyone please tell me what I can do to get tesseract working? Thank you!

**EDIT**
When I run brew link leptonica, I get the following error:

```
Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/leptonica/1.69/bin/yuvtest
Target /usr/local/bin/yuvtest already exists. You may need to delete it.
```

Answer (score 5):

Now, as of September 2019, there are no longer any optional install flags available

```
brew options tesseract
```

yield nothing. But,

```
brew info tesseract
```

yields the following key info:

```
This formula contains only the "eng", "osd", and "snum" language data files.
If you need all the other supported languages, `brew install tesseract-lang`.
```

Therefore, to get all of the languages installed, you need to now install a separate library called `tesseract-lang`.

Updated installation:

```
brew install tesseract
brew install tesseract-lang
```

Hope this helps.

*old in case this is useful:*

Now, as of January 2019, Tesseract installs fine via homebrew, as long as you have xquartz installed first, `brew cask install xquartz`. Then you can do the following: `brew install tesseract --with-all-languages --with-serial-num-pack --with-training-tools`

Comment: The second line returns `Error: invalid option: --with-all-languages` for me

Comment: @jtlz2 thanks for the heads up. The formula changed. `brew info tesseract` yields the following information: ```This formula contains only the "eng", "osd", and "snum" language data files.
If you need all the other supported languages, `brew install tesseract-lang`.``` Therefore there are no more options available. I am updating my answer to reflect this change. Cheers

Comment: Happy to have helped. Do the training-tools still install?

Comment: @jtlz2 if you run `brew options tesseract` you will see there are no more options that install optionally with tesseract, meaning that is the answer to your question-- no `--with-training-tools` option.

Comment: Getting read only file system while downloading language pack in Mac Monterey, works fine in Big Sur

Answer (score 2):

After installing / removing and re-installing tesseract i found the solution for the same problem you have. On your terminal logs, while installing tesseract, you will see:

Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully

The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/convertfilestopdf
Target /usr/local/bin/convertfilestopdf
already exists.
You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/convertfilestopdf'
To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite leptonica

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run leptonica

What i did was running:  brew link --overwrite leptonica

"Linking /usr/local/Cellar/leptonica/1.71_1... 45 symlinks created"

Everything should work perfectly.

Hope this can be a help for you

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a bit silly, but have you tried deleting yuvtest? I just tried it myself - the file is automatically generated by brew link leptonica. As for why it isn't working, is it possible you had some version of leptonica/tesseract installed previously? Another reasonable guess at a fix would be

```
brew uninstall tesseract; brew install tesseract
```

So far as I know, image magick being installed shouldn't matter for tesseract. They don't have anything in common.

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract is now dependent on Leptonica being installed.

The error messages you are seeing relate to these files:

> Leptonica is configured to handle image I/O using these external libraries: libjpeg, libtiff, libpng, libz, libgif, libwebp.
>
> These libraries are easy to obtain. For example, using the debian package manager:
>   sudo apt-get install 
>   where  = {libpng12-dev, libjpeg62-dev, libtiff4-dev}.

Source: [Leptonica unofficial documentation](http://tpgit.github.io/UnOfficialLeptDocs/leptonica/README.html#i-o-libraries-leptonica-is-dependent-on)

I found that homebrew would install some but not all of the libraries.