# How to setup and running Tesseract OCR for PHP (opensource)?

Tags: php, ocr, tesseract

I have installed the Tesseract OCR via MacPorts based on the documentation provided on the GitHUb, and they were installed successfully, and

However, I am trying to use Tesseract OCR for PHP (https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php), so I download the zip and include the library to my php file, and use the

```
echo (new TesseractOCR('text.png'))
->run();
```

but nothing is showing up.

Below is the full code in the php

```
<?php 

REQUIRE_ONCE __DIR__.'/src/TesseractOCR.php';

echo (new TesseractOCR('text.png'))
    ->run(); 

?>
```

My error log has this entry:

> sh: tesseract: command not found

If you share me some lights on how to get this work, it will be great!

Comment: any errors in apache error log file

Comment: Yes is has an error - "sh: tesseract: command not found", but I thought I have installed the tesseract successfully via terminal?

Comment: you installed tesseract successfully? are you sure?

Comment: apparently, you didn't. Or maybe the php script cannot resolve the path to the tesseract executable. From what I can see in the sourcecode, it is just executing "tesseract", which assumes that this is on your PATH then. Try to set the full path to the executable via the [executable() method](https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php/blob/master/src/TesseractOCR.php#L92).

Answer (score 7):

In order to use Tesseract OCR you may need to follow following steps:

**1) Install Tesseract OCR into your system For installation**

please checkout:https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki.

For Ubuntu Linux System you can run :

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

**2) Make composer.json file with following content:**

```
{"require":{"thiagoalessio/tesseract_ocr": "1.0.0-RC"}}
```

**3) Execute command from terminal**

```
composer install
```

**4) Finally, Do PHP  Code:**

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
echo (new TesseractOCR('test.png'))->run();
```

Hope this will works for you,

Comment: Hi Haresh. I have tried the steps you provided using composer, however still not working, and the error logs still saying sh: tesseract: command not found. On the Terminal, I can see the Tesseract has been installed by show all available options in the screen, I am not sure what executable path should be specified under executable() method?

Comment: okay got it, Actually tesseract-ocr command is not properly configure in your system please check out step 1 of my answer.  and Can you tell me what is your operating System?

Comment: Im using Mac El Capitain OS, I cound the executable file which is under /opt/local/bin/tesseract

Comment: try to set `/opt/local/bin/tesseract` value to your system path envirnoment variable please check out http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/ to setup path variable

Comment: After setting path variable reopen terminal and use `tesseract -v` command to check proper installation.

Comment: I have changed the variable $executable = '/opt/local/bin/tesseract'; I could see the tesseract was processing but still with the new error - Warning in pixReadMemPng: work-around: writing to a temp file
Error in pixReadMemPng: tmpfile stream not opened
Error in pixReadMem: png: no pix returned
Error during processing.

Comment: please follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140753/tesseract-install-mac-os for resolve new error

Comment: that's perfect. fast, simple & easy to run

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to insert after require_once
use thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR;

Basically to work, you can simple do it:

```
<?php

require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";
use thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR;

$ocr = new TesseractOCR("17.png");
$content = $ocr->run();
echo $content;
```