# How can I use tesseract-ocr-for-php on windows?

Tags: php, windows, ocr, tesseract

I have installed the [Tesseract OCR](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki)  based on the documentation provided on the GitHub.

Tesseract is working fine I check it by running from cmd.

However, I am trying to use Tesseract OCR for PHP ([tesseract-ocr-for-php](https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php)). I Clone it and follow the steps on GitHub.

I make index.php in a folder and paste the code below.

```
   <?php
    require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
    echo (new TesseractOCR('test.png'))->run();
   ?>
```

**Output**
this only shows 
run()

This code works fine for me when I copy the installed setup of Tesseract OCR from C drive to my project folder.

**Why this not work if I don't copy the installed setup to my project folder?**

Comment: I assume `test.png` is in the same dir as `index.php`?

Comment: Another thing to debug, try assigning the created TesseractOCR to a variable and see var_dump it to see if it contains anything useful. I.e `$ts = new TesseractOCR('test.png')` then `var_dump($ts)`. Not sure if it will hold anything helpful or not.

Comment: not work. both are in same dir

Comment: i tried vardump();.....................................                                                                                                       object(TesseractOCR)[3]
  private 'image' => string 'text.png' (length=8)
  private 'executable' => string 'tesseract' (length=9)
  private 'tessdataDir' => null
  private 'userWords' => null
  private 'userPatterns' => null
  private 'languages' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private 'psm' => null
  private 'configs' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private 'statusQuietMode' => boolean false      @webnoob

Comment: Try adding `->buildCommand()` instead of `->run()` and see what is echo'd out.

Comment: same response @webnoob

Comment: Have you installed in a similar way to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38091060/how-to-setup-and-running-tesseract-ocr-for-php-opensource ?

Comment: I am on windows.i download the setup form Tesseract OCR wiki and installed it

Comment: In that case, sorry, I'm not sure what to do. Try the IRC channel: `#tesseract-ocr-for-php`

Comment: I download from the link (https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki)

Comment: thanks for your Time @webnoob

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup and running Tesseract OCR for PHP (opensource)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38091060/how-to-setup-and-running-tesseract-ocr-for-php-opensource)

Comment: my question is different from that @A.Raza and the question is not answer yet