# Get Text From Image in python

Tags: python-3.x, image, txt

How do I get the text from a image? Can somebody help? I am using a MacBook. I searched a bunch of things, but those were for Windows users.

Comment: Funny that you didn't find anything on the net. You can try `pytesseract`. [Installation on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54204872/18667225).

Answer (score 0):

Use pytesseract for the same. Ref to this link - "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-extract-text-from-images-with-python/"